# Inequality: multivariate normal distribition

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, inequalities

Let $p(u,x)=\frac{1}{(4\pi u)^{q/2}}e^{-|x|^2/(4u)},u>0,x \in \mathbb{R}^q.$

1. Prove that for $r\geq 0,c>1$ there exists $C>0$ (depending on $r,c$) such that $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^q,u>0,\frac{|x|^{2r}}{u^r}p(u,x) \leq Cp(cu,x).$$
2. Deduce that for $n \in \mathbb{N}^q,k \in \mathbb{N},$ there exists $C'>0$ such that $|\partial_x^n\partial_u^k p(u,x)| \leq C' u^{-|n|/2-k}p(cu,x)$ where $\partial^n_x=\partial x_1^{n_1}...\partial x_q^{n_q}$

1 follows from $\frac{|x|^{2}}{4ur}(1-\frac{1}{c}) \leq e^{\frac{|x|^2}{4ur}(1-1/c)}$ and we choose $C=c^{q/2} 4^r(r+1)^r/(1-1/c)^r$

How to deduce 2 (for simplicity we can take $q=1)$? *Is it possible to prove the inequality using induction*? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\p\partial$By induction,
$$\p_u^k p(u,x)=\frac1{u^k}\,P_k\Big(\frac{|x|^2}u\Big)p(u,x)
=\frac K{u^{k+q/2}}\,P_k\Big(\frac{|x|^2}u\Big)e^{-|x|^2/(4u)}, \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $K$ is a real number not depending on $u$ or $x$, and $P_k(z)$ is a polynomial (with coefficients not depending on $u$ or $x$).

Next, for any polynomial $P$ (in $q$ variables) and any $j=1,\dots,q$, there is another polynomial $Q_j$ (in $q$ variables) such that
$$\p_{x_j} \Big(P\Big(\frac{x}{u^{1/2}}\Big)e^{-|x|^2/(4u)}\Big)
=\frac1{u^{1/2}}\,Q_j\Big(\frac{x}{u^{1/2}}\Big)e^{-|x|^2/(4u)}.$$
So, in view of \eqref{1},for some polynomial $R$ (in $q$ variables) and all real $u>0$,
$$|\p_x^n\p_u^k p(u,x)|
=\frac1{u^{|n|/2+k+q/2}}\,\Big|R\Big(\frac{x}{u^{1/2}}\Big)\Big|e^{-|x|^2/(4u)} \\ 
\le \frac C{u^{|n|/2+k+q/2}}\,e^{-|x|^2/(4cu)}
=\frac{C_1}{u^{k+|n|/2}}\,p(cu,x),$$
where $C$ and $C_1$ are positive real numbers not depending on $u$ or $x$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: @mathex : Yes, there should be a number of ways to prove this, including writing $p$ as such a product. I did think about the Leibnitz rule, but  that recurrence seemed harder to use. Anyhow, do you agree with the proof presented in my answer? If so, could you please finalize this?